# How to scan a screen and find a certain color on screen

Tags: c#

I want my program to be able to scan the pixels of the processes main window to be able to determine what color is where.. i have seen other questions who want the color of a specific point but that doesn't help what i am trying to do. I am trying to create a bot to play Tetris and i want it to establish when it has a certain block based on the color in the game. The problem is I have no idea ho to go about this seeing how anything i look up is to find the pixel of somewhere i click when i need the bot to be able to scan for it by itself.

Comment: If you want to write an AI for your game, you should have it make decisions using whatever internal model of the blocks and their positions you are currently using to render the screen, not by sampling the colors of pixels in the view.

Comment: If i am using a 2d matrix and it knows exactly where everything is all it needs to know is what exactly it is controlling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are approaching the issue from the wrong side. You want exactly what you found in answers to other questions: the color of a pixel at a known position of your tetris area. You aren't interested in the colors of the window frame or the other stuff around.
My advice: Calculate the position of the single squares and query the color of one pixel at the square's center. You will get as many pixels as squares. The other way would give you maybe hundret times more data with much less use...